# use of decltype(auto) <func> before deduction of auto

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, decltype, type-deduction

Following situation:

```
#include <stdint.h>

class C
{
public:
    C()=default;
    ~C()=default;
    template<uint8_t> struct integconst
    {
    };

    int m1(integconst<8>);
    int m2(integconst<8>);
    decltype(auto) masterMethod(int opMode);
private:
};

int C::m1(integconst<8>) {return 1;}
int C::m2(integconst<8>) {return 2;}

decltype(auto) C::masterMethod(int opMode)
{
    switch(opMode)
    {
    case 1:
            return m1(integconst<sizeof(uintptr_t)>{}); break;
    case 2:
            return m2(integconst<sizeof(uintptr_t)>{}); break;
    default:
            return m1(integconst<sizeof(uintptr_t)>{}); break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    C obj;
    int bla=obj.masterMethod(1);
    return 0;
}
```

putting the above simplified example will work with no problems. but when I try to seperate the implementation and declaration in separate files ([full example here](https://onlinegdb.com/BkdX3mdUm)) then I get the error

`main.cpp: error: use of 'decltype(auto) C::masterMethod(int)' before deduction of 'auto'`. Moving the implementation directly to the class itself solves the problem (or implementing the methods within the same file), but I don't really understand why? Can somebody explain me why the compiler does not know the type of decltype(auto) yet, respecitvley when does the comiler start to resolve the return types of "auto"? How would one separate the implementation and declaration as I would like to do it?

Comment: the compiler needs a definition of the function to deduce the type

Comment: @Tyker but the definition is already in the *.cpp-file?

Comment: Imagine you include such a header (that does not have definition of such a method) to a different .cpp file, which has methods that invoke it (as is the case in the full example, that you show). How should the compiler decide what `auto` should resolve to, in other .cpp files, which doesn't contain the definition?

Comment: c++ works per translation unit; and each other doesn't see the content of the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every source file (`.cpp` file or `.cc` file) has to stand on its own. The standard calls these files *translation units*, because the behaviour of the program is the same *as-if* all those files are translated into machine language as separate units, and only then the machine code is linked into one program.

Standing "on its own" means that the source file together with all files included in it have to convey all information to translate the source file. If you put the `masterMethod` in one source file and `main` in a different source file, the compiler has no idea which type is returned by `masterMethod` when compiling main.

The answer to your question

> How would one seperate implementation and declaration as I would like to do it?

Is thus: Either you put the source code of the function in the header file, or you give up on using return type deduction. If you put the source code into the header file, you don't need to put it *inside* the class definition, as long as you declare it inline.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the return type deduction, you can't separate the declaration and its definition into different files. At the time of compilation, the compiler must be able to know what does 'masterMethod' returns.

I think this is similar to below question:

[`auto` return type in context of class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694607/auto-return-type-in-context-of-class-members)