# Return vector as auto from function

Tags: angular, c++, c++11

Is it possible to return std::vector as auto?
For example:

```
auto retVec() {
  std::vector<int> vec_l;

  l.push_back(1);
  l.push_back(2);

  return vec_l;
}
...
auto ret_vec = retVec();
for (auto& it : ret_vec) {
}
```

when I write something like this I get an error:

1. error: use of `auto retVec()` before deduction of `auto` --->
       `auto ret_vec = retVec(**)**;`
2. error: unable to deduce `auto&&` from `ret_vec` ---> `for (auto it :
   **ret_vec**) {`

How do I actually write this?

**UPDATE**: 
I'm sorry. I use this retVec as method in class and it doesn't work. When I use it as function in class - everything work fine. My mistake in formulating the question.

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2396fbfb00986795)

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: For posterity, can you add the compiler version and command you ran to compile as part of the question?

Comment: This is an instance when adding *all* the tags is detrimental to your question. This simply cannot be valid C++11.

Comment: -1 In addition to what doron and StoryTeller wrote, please add [_complete_ relevant source code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your original question was incomplete, so people naturally assumed the simplest correct answer. Now that you have a different question, you would need a different thread about member functions, with a 100% clear test case. However, I doubt you need to post that, as we must have one of those already.

Comment: @underscore_d ty. I already find the answer. I should write definition and realization in same *.h file. My mistake in formulating the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694607/auto-return-type-in-context-of-class-members

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are compiling for the C++11 standard. You need  to compile for at least the C++14 standard as the [deduced return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is only available starting with C++14. The reference states:

> In a function declaration that does not use the trailing return type
>   syntax, the keyword `auto` indicates that the return type will be
>   deduced from the operand of its `return` statement using the rules for
>   template argument deduction.

Comment: Blazing fast : ) might want to edit this link into the answer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto, as it shows '(since C++14)' next to `auto function`

Comment: @Ron It strange, because I use g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04) 7.3.0 and  flag -std=c++17 :)

Comment: @Max You are compiling for C++11 standard. The [C++17 version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecb7ff77afcee5a0) does not produce the above error.

Comment: @Ron I'm sorry. I use this retVec as method in class and it doesn't work. When I use it as function in class - everything work fine. My mistake in formulating the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can see this error on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/783c13d9cf5faebd) when compiling with `-std=c++11`, but this works as intended [when compiled with `-std=c++14`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a565e7b9450fdf07).

Note that gcc even outputs a hint at this:

> main.cpp:8:13: note: deduced return type only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14

Deducted return type using `auto` is indeed a [C++14 feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto), see Item (3).

Comment: thank you for reply, I update question. My mistake in formulating the question.

Answer (score 3):

This works since C++14 (see [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/paV8IF)) and not with C++11 ([here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/voUUMV)).

Comment: thank you for reply, I update question. My mistake in formulating the question.